# Chained payments, how to transfer payments for a non paypal user

Tags: paypal

I know this not a technical question, posting here, because paypal website recommends stackoverflow as their preferred 'helpdesk' partner.

In my application, we are using chained payments. We sit as a conduit between a freelancer and an employer. We have no means to detect if the employers/freelancers email address is registered with paypal. My questions are

1) is it possible to send an  invoice to a person who doesn't have the email address  registered with paypal at the time he receives the invoice, and he can later registers that email address with the paypal to see the invoice?

2) Is it possible to send money to a person/freelancer who doesn't have an account at the time he receives money, but later registers his email address with paypal and withdraws the money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both answers are yes. followed are screenshots for sending sending invoice via web. You will get pretty much the same result via api.

[image]